# Tabs Design UI pattern in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

We are designing a new application for Android and we want to make it consistent with the new designing guidelines google gave not long ago.

Our problem is that our app has these 5 main sections:
- City
- Attractions
- Todo
- Weather
- Emergency

We are considering using "fixed tabs" for each one of them but the problem is that they will become scrollable as there are too many and wont fit on the screen. We also considered to use Scrollable tabs but views are really different from each other and we think is difficult to scroll from the first one to the last one in case of necessity.

Don't really know if this is the correct way to do it or you can gave me a little advice here how to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty good resource: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

There are lots of ideas there. Maybe you can copy or edit one.